# Cannot Update Value in Struct Solidity

Tags: solidity

I can't update the values in my solidity struct. I'm using hardhat ethers.

Reading the other posts, I have tried adding a .connect(user2) for my test. I have also used storage in my .sol file.

Console.log shows the name and status remains the same even after I run the .setMemberInactive(0) function which is supposed to change the name and status

```
1 0
Jane
2 0
Jane
```

Anyone knows what have I done wrong here?

Solidity:

```
enum Status {
    Active,
    Inactive
}
struct Member {
    string name;
    Status status;
}
Member[] public members;
uint256 public membersCount;

function addMember(string memory _name) external {
    Member memory member = Member(_name, Status.Active);
    members.push(member);
    membersCount++;
}

// todo not working
function setMemberInactive(uint256 index) external {
    Member storage member = members[index];
    member.name = "Jeremy";
    member.status = Status.Inactive;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// todo Changing Enum Value not Working
it("should change member status", async () => {
  let member = await demoContract.members(0);
  console.log("1", member.status);
  console.log(member.name);
  let tx = await demoContract.connect(user2).setMemberInactive(0);
  await tx.wait();
  console.log("2", member.status);
  console.log(member.name);
});
```

Comment: Please include the code for setMemberInactive

Comment: so sorry, i missed out the setMemberInactive function. I have added that in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The struct values were actually updated but issue was I didn't get the updated copy of the member. I needed to call member = await demoContract.members(0); and use the updated copy.

Thus, there is no issue with my solidity code. The problem lies in the javascript test code

below is the working code

```
 it("should change member status", async () => {
      let member;
      member = await demoContract.members(0);
      expect(member.name).to.be.equal("Jane");
      expect(member.status).to.be.equal(0);
      await demoContract.connect(user2).setMemberInactive(0);
      member = await demoContract.members(0);
      expect(member.name).to.be.equal("Jeremy");
      expect(member.status).to.be.equal(1);
    });
```